# A way to do unit testing online? (i.e. Google)?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, pear

I'm trying to setup phpUnit via my host however, they are severely outdated and the documentation on how to use it is non-existent (hosts version).  I'm wondering is there a way to do online unit testing, where the framework is hosted somewhere other than my server?

**For example does Google have a solution where I can just include a file from Google's server?**

UPDATE:

OK so apparently there is no cloud based way to run phpUnit.  So my problem is installing it. My host has a PEAR installer (I'm not familiar with how PEAR really works yet).  However, the version that they have is phpUnit2 which is apparently related to phpUnit (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).  But that is all I can really find.

According to the above link, the main way to install phpUnit is through PEAR :
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

It requires that I change channels, however, it doesn't look like I have access to do that.  Some are suggesting I can just copy the files up to my server and use them that way.  Is that the best way for me to do this?  Are there other settings I need to change (on my server) to make this work?

Any information is much appreciated.

Comment: You could also set up your own server on EC2 for very cheap.  The cheapest server (micro instance) is free for the first year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's no need to use your host's version; the entire library is just a simple file. Go [download it yourself from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpunit/), upload it to your server, and you should be off and running.

Comment: So basically it is like installing the jQuery framework.  You just download the framework and put it on your server and then reference the proper files in your .php tests?

Comment: Yes.  See [setting the include path](http://au.php.net/set_include_path) for examples; just ensure that your downloaded version is earlier in the path than any other version and it'll find that first.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you will find something like this because in order to unit test a system you need to have access to the code and a remote site isn't able to get that access (i.e. the ability to call functions built into your application).